Sanity check fails when integrating by parts
Suppose we have a one-dimensional autonomous ODE defined by $\frac{dx}{dt} = x - x^2$. Let us take the initial condition $x(0) = -2$. For all $x \in (-\infty, 0)$, $x - x^2 < 0$, so the point should move in the negative direction.
Since $\frac{1}{x-x^2} = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x-1}$, integrating by parts we arrive at
$
\log |x| - \log |x-1| = t + C
$
which, taking the initial condition into account, gives
$
\frac{x}{x-1} = e^{C+t}. 
$
But this cannot happen, because the left-hand side is a positive number of magnitude close to 1, and the right-hand side grows exponentially. What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks in advance!

What makes you say the left-hand side has magnitude close to $1$? If $x$ is close to $1$, then $\frac{x}{x-1}$ will be very big

I mean that at $t = 0$, $x(0)/(x(0)-1) = 2/3$. As $t \to \infty$, the point should be moving towards $-\infty$ because the derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$ is negative, and $x(t)/(x(t)-1)$ should approach $1$.

Negative derivative everywhere doesn't mean it will tend to $-\infty$ as $t\to\infty$. For a counterexample take something like $\frac{1}{t}$ for $t\in(0,\infty)$.

Just looking at a plot of the right hand side should convince you that if you start with $x_0 < 0$ then $x(t) \to -\infty$, if $x_0 = 0$ then $x(t) = 0$, otherwise $x(t) \to 1$.

From $1/x - 1/(x-1)$ you should expect the graph to have horizontal asymptotes at $x = 0$ and $x = 1$.  This divides the plane into three horizontal slabs.  Which slab has the solution you found in it?  What signs do $x$ and $x -1$ have in each slab?

@copper.hat yes, but the problem is that the formal solution is $x(t) = 2/(2 - 3e^{-t})$ (see the answer below, or Wolfram Alpha), which is undefined at $\log(3/2)$ and tends to $x = 1$ as $t \to \infty$.

@toghrul Part of my comment is incorrect, for $x_0<0$ $x(t)$ blows up (or rather down) in finite time.

Setting $t=0$ in your final equation gives $$\frac{2}{3}=e^C.$$ Now the equation $$\frac{x}{x-1}=2/3e^t$$ gives $$x(t)=\frac2{2-3e^{-t}}$$ which is a valid solution. What is your worry?

Thank you for the answer. My worry is that the solution does not match the physical intuition: A) what happens at time $t = \log (3/2)$, which gives $2 - 3e^{-t} = 0$? B) Your solution asymptotically tends to $x = 1$, but because $dx(t)/dt < 0$ at $t = 0$ and for all $x(t) < 0$, I would expect the point to move only to the left...

At $t=\log(3/2)$, $x$ tends to $-\infty$ (from the left), not $1$.

ok, I understand: the issue is that unlike linear ODEs, not every non-linear autonomous ODE has a solution defined on $[0, \infty)$: one needs Picard's theorem and such. The ODE I gave cannot model a physical system that is defined at all times. Thanks!
